# Reading Azure Blob - DownloadToAsync Throws an exception

Tags: vb.net, azure-blob-storage

Following is the code which is trying to read XML from the Azure Blob,

```
 Dim memStream As New IO.MemoryStream
 memStream.Flush()
 memStream.Position = 0
 blobClient.DownloadToAsync(memStream).Wait()
```

It throws an exception on memStream. File does exists in the container.

> ReadTimeout = 'memStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Answer (score 0):

The `Await` is for an asynchronous operation, because why do it asynchronous and then wait for it?, but also the `Await` must be asynchronous

So your code would look like

```vb
Private Async Sub Foo()
    Dim connectionString = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    Dim BlobClient As New BlockBlobClient(connectionString, "test", "test.txt")
    Dim memStream As New IO.MemoryStream
    memStream.Flush()
    memStream.Position = 0
    Await BlobClient.DownloadToAsync(memStream)
End Sub
```

Your method `Sub` or `Function` must be marked `Async`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: The containing method should be marked `Async` as well

Comment: iam unsure what you mean?

Comment: @nbk you can only use `Await` when the method (sub or function) is `Async`.  Otherwise you will get an error.